# Playwright Framework : Is there a way we can execute dependent tests in playwright?

Tags: typescript, annotations, testng, e2e-testing, playwright

Playwright Framework : Is there a way we can execute dependent tests in playwright?
Like for example, we use 'depends on' method using TestNg annotations, or using Priority annotations in Selenium Webdriver.
I have a test case which is dependent on the other test case. The latter one is actually for submitting an application first. So, only by using the submitted ID, I can run my other test cases. So, I can either create that test script as a method and call that method in my test scripts so I am not re-using the same test script again. But instead I wanted to run this test case before the other ones. So, is there a way in Playwright that we can execute a specific test cases before some dependent test cases?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

You can run your test blocks one after another using test.describe.serial mode.

e.g.

```
test.describe.serial("Running test sequentially", ()=>{

    test("Test block 1 : ", async()=>{
        //enter code here
    });

    test("Test block 2 : ", async()=>{
        //enter code here
    });

});
```

But there is a catch in using test.describe.serial mode, subsequent tests won’t be run if an earlier test fails. It is also not works with the flags like fullyParalell: false, or --max-failures, or --bail last two works in running independent test blocks.

I have raised a defect and feature to be added in Playwright to not skip subsequent test if an earlier test fails. Please find the links below:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/17266

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/16199