# With Playwright is there a way to run a single test after all others have completed?

Tags: javascript, playwright, end-to-end

I have a large set of tests running in Playwright which we have shard in out CI environment. We use a global setup file for the authentication on the application which is shared in each shard.

The problem I have is I want to to be able to test the logout flow of the application in Playwright but if I have the logout test just mixed in with the rest of the tests then when the logout flow test runs, all tests after that fail because the auth session has been ended.

Is there a way I can configure Playwright to say "Run this test last"?

Looking at the configuration docs I can't see anything obvious that would allow me to do this.

Comment: Perhaps have the test confirm the logout, then log back in within the same test / afterAll within that logout suite. I dont believe there is a way of 'running a test last'

Comment: Related: [Playwright Framework : Is there a way we can execute dependent tests in playwright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338339/playwright-framework-is-there-a-way-we-can-execute-dependent-tests-in-playwrig), [How to run Playwright spec files in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419841/how-to-run-playwright-spec-files-in-order)

Comment: Logging back in wont work as the tests in my CI environment are shard so there would be no way for me to get the browser state back to the other shard runs.

Comment: I could use the naming method and call the file `zzzz-logout.spec.ts` but again there is no guarantee that it would run last, only last in the shard that it runs in.